How to set *all* textures to closest (instead of linear) by default (how to disable pixel interpolation)?
Question
I've used the answer provided in this Reddit comment:

The fix is simply to select the image texture node you want to make pixellated in your material and change the top drop-down box from "Linear" to "Closest."

but this is a solely retroactive operation, and appears to be object-specific (rather than texture-specific). Consequently, how can I make all textures default to closest (rather than linear) interpolation?
Non-Duplicates
This Reddit post requests a way to retroactively modify all textures in all contexts in a .blend to be closest:

I'm doing renders of imported minecraft worlds (via an add-on called MCPrep). On import all textures are 16x16 and set to linear, thus extremely blury. You can go into shading and change the first node to closest, but you have to texture by texture.
Is there a way to in mass change all textures to closest? I'm new to Blender, for all I know this could actually be quite simple.

